# pandas difference between datetime64[ns] in milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, milliseconds

How to get the difference in milliseconds of these two columns:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


def datetime_generator():
    day = np.random.randint(1, 7 + 1)
    hour = np.random.randint(0, 23 + 1)
    minute = np.random.randint(0, 59 + 1)
    second = np.random.randint(0, 59 + 1)
    millisecond = np.random.randint(0, 999999 + 1)

    return datetime(2018, 1, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond)

df = pd.DataFrame({'ts1': [datetime_generator() for i in range(10)],
                         'ts2': [datetime_generator() for i in range(10)]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Get the timedeltas, then read & convert their microseconds.

```
df["new"] = df.ts1 - df.ts2
df["new"] = df.new.apply(lambda x: x.microseconds/1000)
```

---

**This old answer only gets the microseconds**

`.dt.microsecond` is the way

```
df["new"] = df.ts1.dt.microsecond - df.ts2.dt.microsecond
```

Note the conversion ratio between micro and mili seconds is `1000:1` so...

```
df["new"] = (df.ts1.dt.microsecond - df.ts2.dt.microsecond)/1000
```

There is no `.dt.milisecond` equivalent as far as I can tell.

Comment: this ignores everything but the milliseconds so, for instance, 2018-01-01 12:00:01.1 - 2018-01-01 12:00:00.2 will be -1000000 instead of 9000000

Comment: Ohhh! @BlueMoon I see what you want now. I will edit my answer